# Add desktop picture into HTML email template

Tags: html, image, html-email

For html email templates i'm aware that the images will only show if they come from the web (http://) but how do i put my own personal picture not from the web in my html code and still have it show up properly in the email templates i send out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image would have to be hosted on the web somewhere. You could use imgur or another image hosting service. Once you have your image hosted somewhere take the url for the image itself and place that in your html.

EDIT: from @Syfer

> Free hosting is not recommended. They tend to have a quota of counts before the links start showing images which might say hot linking is not allowed (or something similar). If you the email is for a client i would suggest hosting on their server or be ready to be marked as spam by the ESP's. – Syfer

Comment: Free hosting is not recommended. They tend to have a quota of counts before the links start showing images which might say _hot linking is not allowed_ (or something similar). If you the email is for a client i would suggest hosting on their server or be ready to be marked as spam by the ESP's.

Comment: Good advice above me, I would try what @Syfer is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Most email systems have an image library or folder that can contain your images. Its good practice to host the images on the same IP as where the mail is sent from. I know mailChimp and CampaignMonitor has this feature.